# How to get an array of unsigned int from C++ to C#?

Tags: c#, c++, marshalling

I'm new to C# and try to find an equivalent C# code for populating array of int from a dll file.

```
    // in C++
unsigned int MyFunc(unsigned int* ids, unsigned int* size);


//usage of the function in C++


{

    //...
    unsigned int status = 0;
    unsigned int myIds[2000];
    unsigned int size = sizeof(myIds) / sizeof(myIds[0]);
    //invoke the function to fill myIds
    status = MyFunc(myIds, &size);

    //...
}
```

```
//in C#

[DllImport("MyFunc")]
private static extern uint MyFunc(ref uint ids, ref uint size);


//usage of the function in C#

{

    //...
    uint[] myIds = new uint[2000];
    uint size = (uint)myIds.Length;
    uint status = MyFunc(ref myIds, ref size);//error compilation .. cannot convert from ref uint[] to ref uint 
//...
}
```

How can I get myIds to be populated in C#?

Comment: Naitve C++ or C++ .NET? Your tags indicated Native C++, but I find it better to ask.

Comment: I use the code above from a native C++ code

Answer (score 0):

You pass ref to single unsigned integer in the `[DllImport("MyFunc")]
private static extern uint MyFunc(ref uint ids, ref uint size);`

You should pass a ref to array of unsigned integers, not just one unsigned integer to be accepted as a parameter. The error is pretty straightforward.

Once you do that, your code would look like:
`[DllImport("MyFunc")]
private static extern uint MyFunc(ref uint[] ids, ref uint size);`

Comment: Thank you! I just check, no error is generated, but unfortunately I do not receive anything in ids array... maybe I try to access the data in the array in other way.. The status return value is C# is an error.. what could be the problem? In C++ code it works perfectly!!

Comment: You still have to copy the managed array to unmanaged memory.

Comment: @bioan The thing jdweng said is correct. Take a look at marshalling https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/default-marshaling-for-arrays

Comment: Hi! I need the code above to be used in a project developed in C# starting from an existing one written in native C++. Why should i need to copy the managed array to unmanaged memory? Sorry for asking stupid questions, is the first time i have to deal with such terminology..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2341595/calling-a-c-method-with-a-c-style-array-as-a-parameter-from-c-sharp-net