# Exchange structures (envolving pointers to other structures) between C and C#

Tags: c#, pinvoke, marshalling

I want to use PInvoke to bring to managed side something this:

(C code)

> typedef struct{
>       //some fields...
>   } A;
>
> type struct{
>       A* a;
>   } B;
>
> int getB(B* destination){  //destionation will be an output parameter to C#
>       //puts an B in 'destination'
>       return 0;
>   }

Now, I need a way to tell managed side how to marshalling B from C to C# structure or class. I've tryed many things such as IntPtr fields, MarchalAs atributes, but with no success. I will not expose here the code that I've tryed to keep the question simple. However i could do it as long answers arrive.

Comment: Here is a very similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2305215/passing-objects-between-c-and-c/2305249#2305249

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, although similar, it is not the same problem. I want to marshal information from C to C#. "nadavg" wants to marshal information from C# to C. In other worlds, "nadavg" could avoid to have struct pointers in its structures. I can't. My problem only exists due to pointers to other strutures.

Answer (score 0):

If it were me, I would just use unsafe code and use pointers on the C# side:

```
public unsafe class UnmanagedStuff {

    public struct A {
        // some fields
    }

    public struct B {
        public A* a;
    }

    // Add appropriate PInvoke attribute here
    public static extern int getB(B* destination);

    public static void UseBForSomething() {

        B b;
        getB(&b);

        // Do something with b

    }

}
```

Comment: That's right. This is (almost) the code i need to C# side. Almost because the UseBForSomething body could not be soo simple since we are working with both managed and unmaneged memory. But you have to provide the A and B struct with the apropriate atributes to "teach" the CLR marshalling the structures. And my question is what atributes do i need..

Comment: We'd need to know the contents of the structs to know any specifics.  Assuming they just contain basic value types and you represent them equivalently in C#, the default handling should be fine.

Comment: A* (content of struct B) is not a value type. And that's the problem.. If i have A insted of A* the solution would be very easy.

Comment: Pointers can be passed to unmanaged functions without any special handling, just like ints or floats.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using the Marshal class.

```
// Define a C# struct to match the unmanaged one
struct B
{
    IntPtr a;
}

[DllImport("dllName")]
extern int getB(IntPtr destination);

B GetB()
{
    IntPtr ptrToB = IntPtr.Zero;
    getB(ptrToB);
    return (B)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptrToB, typeof(B));
}
```

Comment: You are not allocating the managed memory to B. It must be IntPtr ptrToB = Marchal.AllocHGlobal(Marchal.sizeof(B)); Even so, doing this only brings to me the value of pointer A. I don't want the value, i need the pointed data.

Comment: @Zé Carlos: You can then call `Marshal.PtrToStructure(b.a, typeof(A));` to get the pointed data (assuming you have defined the corresponding 'A' structure);