# How to expose C# Tuples to C++

Tags: c#, c++, com, interop, com-interop

I'm a C++ developer who is currently writing a library in C# which has to be exposed to C++. As of now I'm using Tuples in C# to get a list of Pair of strings, which is described in the following structure.

```
public struct ProductInfo
{
    string ProductID;
    List<Tuple<String,String>> attributes;
};
```

I would like to expose this structure to C++. I'm expecting C++ developers to use std::pair to fill in. But I'm not sure how to Marshal the same from C++ to C#. My googling didn't give me much help. Can somebody throw some light on this?

Comment: What exactly is your specific question ?

Comment: My question is how to marshal, the values in std::pair<string,string> to Tuples<string, string>

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing objects between C# and C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2305215/passing-objects-between-c-sharp-and-c)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how exactly you want the interop to work, you want either [How To Marshal Structures Using PInvoke](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/how-to-marshal-structures-using-pinvoke) or [SWIG](http://www.swig.org).